# Dynamic google sheet cell reference

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How do I have a cell reference A1:A30 this week, but A31:A60 in next week?

I have tried building a week count and using A(1+weekCount):A(30+weekCount) but it doesn’t work

Answer (score 1):

Solved. INDIRECT + string function did the job

Answer (score 0):

today's weeknum is 45 `=WEEKNUM("01/11/2020")` so if you want to start with this week number use:

```
=INDIRECT("A"&(WEEKNUM(TODAY())-44)*30-29&":A"&(WEEKNUM(TODAY())-44)*30)
```

[image]